# Counting data using range from array PHP

Tags: php

I want to counting data using range base from array using PHP..
Here is my array

```
$array = array(
            1.1, 2.2, 3.2, 4.5, 4.2,
            5.4, 6.2, 7.1, 8, 9.4, 10,
            1.7);
```

My expected output is like (the number of range I set manually, Im just want to count how many data which include my role) :

```
1.00 - 2.50 : 3 data
2.51 - 3.50 : 0 data
3.51 - 4.00 : 1 data
```

I try to write like this but it still cannot works

```
$start = 1;        
$end = 2.5;        
$int = 0;
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if ($start>=$value && $end<=$value) {
          $int++;
      }
   }
echo $int;
```

Please help me to resolve this simple case . Thankyou very much

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. It is unclear what you are asking for at the moment.

Comment: Ok sir @vascowhite, I edited my question

Comment: There is no consistency on the *from* of the range and the step

Comment: Yes because I want to count data summary for Grade Point Average in the university

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `range` because it is consistent values. You can use `array_reduce` and `array_filter` to summarise the data.

```
$array = array(1.1, 2.2, 3.2, 4.5, 4.2,5.4, 6.2, 7.1, 8, 9.4, 10,1.7);
$range = array("1.00-2.50","2.51-3.50","3.51-4.00");

$grouped = array_reduce($range, function($c,$v) use($array) {
    $group = array_filter($array,function($x) use ($v){
        $t = explode("-",$v);
        return $x >= $t[0] && $x <= $t[1];
    });

    $c[ $v ] = count( $group );
    return $c;
},array());

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $grouped );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [1.00-2.50] => 3
    [2.51-3.50] => 1
    [3.51-4.00] => 0
)
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstood your question then this should work for you.

```
$array = array(
            1.1, 2.2, 3.2, 4.5, 4.2,
            5.4, 6.2, 7.1, 8, 9.4, 10,
            1.7);

$count = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

   if ($value<ceil($value)) {
        $count[floor($value)."-".ceil($value)]++;
    }
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($count);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
 Array
 (
  [1-2] => 2
  [2-3] => 1
  [3-4] => 1
  [4-5] => 2
  [5-6] => 1
  [6-7] => 1
  [7-8] => 1
  [9-10]=> 1
 )
```

**See demo:** https://eval.in/973669

Comment: Okay this work for me, but how if I using range using decimal. (Im jst edit my question) @being-sunny

Comment: @FatchulAmin Ohh God, you've edited your expected output now..!

Comment: Oh sorry , the number of range I set manually, Im just want to count how many data which include my role from the array